# how to Draw d3.js graph in particular <div> section

Tags: d3.js

i am new to d3.js, i want to generate graph as per example [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885304).

If I can store this file separately and runs it works fine. but I don't know how to add this into my particular  element of my html page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Bootstrap 3, D3.JS implementation</title>
    <SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="d3.v2.min.js"></SCRIPT>

    <meta name="description" content="Source code generated using layoutit.com">
    <meta name="author" content="LayoutIt!">

    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>

  <style>

nav {
  margin-top: 40px;
  padding: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Raleway;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
#nav-3 {
  background: #EEA200;
}

.link-3 {
  transition: 0.4s;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
.link-3:hover {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #EEA200;
  padding: 24px 10px;
}





.axis text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}




</style>
  <body>

    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active">
                            <a class="link-3" href="#">HOME</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="link-3" href="#">LOGIN</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">     
                    <h3>Sample page</h3>        
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12" >
            <div id="svgHere" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
    <script>
    var n = 20, // number of samples
    m = 4; // number of series

var data = d3.range(m).map(function() { return d3.range(n).map(Math.random); });

var margin = {top: 20, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, 1])
    .range([height, 0]);

var x0 = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(d3.range(n))
    .rangeBands([0, width], .2);

var x1 = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(d3.range(m))
    .rangeBands([0, x0.rangeBand()]);

var z = d3.scale.category10();

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x0)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

var svg = d3.select("#svgHere").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("svg:g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g").selectAll("g")
    .data(data)
  .enter().append("g")
    .style("fill", function(d, i) { return z(i); })
    .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(" + x1(i) + ",0)"; })
  .selectAll("rect")
    .data(function(d) { return d; })
  .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("width", x1.rangeBand())
    .attr("height", y)
    .attr("x", function(d, i) { return x0(i); })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return height - y(d); });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

From the above code "here i want to draw graph using d3.js" in this section, I want to add my graph.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Select this `<div>` by ID when you define your SVG variable.

First, give it a (unique) ID:

```
<div id="svgHere"></div>
```

And then:

```
var svg = d3.select("#svgHere")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", someValue)//the width value goes here
    .attr("height", someValue);//the height value goes here
```

Comment: I changed the div as 
<div id="svgHere"></div> and also i changed the svg element as
var svg = **d3.select("#svgHere")**,
    margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom;
but, still it does not working.

Comment: You forgot the most important: `append("svg")`. Look at my answer and do exactly like that. Notice that, in Bostock's example, the SVG is already there.

Comment: I edited the code, given my exact code how t tried to draw graph. Still this does not produce any graph content. "data.tsv" is the file, from which i am reading the records, this i have stored in the exact folder, where i have stored my html file.

Comment: You have *another* problem then. The code in my answer *does* create an SVG in that particular div.

Comment: Yes it works, i made i mistake in adding the id. After trying to add as you given it works fine. Thanks :) As well i am editing my code for others reference.